# MySQL efficiency / combinations

Tags: mysql, performance, combinations

```
CREATE TABLE VanNaar_4P

SELECT

a2.ID as Van,a2.lat as v_lat ,a2.lon as v_lon,

a1.ID as Naar,a1.lat as n_lat ,a1.lon as n_lon

FROM

adressen a1 

JOIN adressen a2;
```

Could this query be written more efficient? I have the feeling it's running way to long for it's size... 
Basically I have a list like this :

```
1 a b
2 d e
3 i w
```

And I need all combinations (some fields per row, based on an unique ID)

Comment: Add an index on the join field(s) and learn how to use EXPLAIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your problem is symmetrical, so you could do

```
CREATE TABLE VanNaar_temp
SELECT
  a2.ID as Van,a2.lat as v_lat ,a2.lon as v_lon,
  a1.ID as Naar,a1.lat as n_lat ,a1.lon as n_lon
FROM adressen a1 
INNER JOIN adressen a2 ON a2.id<a1.id;

CREATE TABLE VanNaar_4P
SELECT * FROM VanNaar_temp;

INSERT INTO VanNaar_4P
SELECT Narr, n_lat, n_lon, Van, v_lat, v_long
FROM VanNaar_temp;

DROP TABLE VanNaar_temp;
```

This leaves out the zero ways, i.e. `Van==Nar`. If you really need them, add

```
INSERT INTO VanNaar_4P
SELECT
  a2.ID as Van,a2.lat as v_lat ,a2.lon as v_lon,
  a1.ID as Naar,a1.lat as n_lat ,a1.lon as n_lon
FROM adressen a1 
INNER JOIN adressen a2 ON a2.id=a1.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about some JOIN condition?

Answer (score 0):

Query every possoble combination:

**[SQLFIddleExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/940af/1)**

```
SELECT
*
FROM tbl t1, tbl t2
```

Your query every possible combination:

```
SELECT
a2.ID as Van,a2.lat as v_lat ,a2.lon as v_lon,
a1.ID as Naar,a1.lat as n_lat ,a1.lon as n_lon
FROM adressen a1, adressen a2
```

Some example data:

```
INSERT INTO tbl
(type, details)
VALUES
('a', 'b'),
('g', 'z'),
('k', 'l'),
('c', 'a');
```

Result:

```
| TYPE | DETAILS |
------------------
|    a |       b |
|    g |       z |
|    k |       l |
|    c |       a |
|    a |       b |
|    g |       z |
|    k |       l |
|    c |       a |
|    a |       b |
|    g |       z |
|    k |       l |
|    c |       a |
|    a |       b |
|    g |       z |
|    k |       l |
|    c |       a |
```